# I need to get my website to fit the screen

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

I have created my website as a fixed layout, with a width of 1600px,
but the webpage on a smaller resolution looks too big. 
What am I supposed to do to make it looks good in every resolution?

Thanks for help

Comment: instead of px you need to use 100% in width.

Comment: Way too broad, way too inspecific

Comment: @MarcB I think it is just a novice question, not a bad one. And it attracts really cool answers :-)

Comment: Guys im new in html and css if I need to change it in percentage, I need to change simply the width of the body or every each attribute that is in px, should be changed in %?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative measures, like `width: 100%`. You can constrain this even more by using `min-width` and `max-width`.

Apart from that, you can use [`CSS media queries`](http://cssmediaqueries.com/) to make styles that only apply if certain conditions are met, like a minimum or maximum width. If you use that, you can change the whole look and feel of your website, for instance by hiding parts on smaller devices or change from a 2 column to a 1 column text presentation on smaller devices.

Comment: So i should change all elements in px to %?

For example I have a div of 150px in how much should I change it?

Comment: Well, not all, but some of them. How much is right, depends on you and on the site structure. But for instance, if you have a table of 1600px and 5 columns of 320px each, you would make those column 1/5 of 1600px = 20%. But it depends on the size of the parent. Not that many elements by default size to their parent, so you only need to change absolute pixel sizes you have currently given. Everything that has an automatic width will probably just size along.

Answer (score 1):

A percentage-based width would change the width depending on the screen size, but you should also use `min-width` to ensure the page doesn't become too thin that it ruins your content.

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

- Use a narrower fixed width. Staying under 1,000 pixels is fairly safe though not perfect
- Use percentages for page width instead, though this is difficult if you need to have a set width for child elements to look right
- **Do a combination of the above and use media queries in your CSS to make your site responsive.  It'll fit every screen width you specify AND you'll have full control over your layout at each trigger point.**

Here is a great resource for learning about responsive sites - this is the way to build a modern website, so though it might seem confusing it's worth every minute you spend on it.

http://bradfrost.github.com/this-is-responsive/resources.html

Good luck.